# R: Comparing the presence of a string in multiple dataframes

Tags: r, comparison, dataframe

I have 6 dataframes:

```
DvE.+

DvE.-

DvS.+

DvS.-

EvS.+

EvS.-
```

and they all have similar structure:

```
                   gene          FDR     log2FC                                                                           annotation
10 c10001_g1_i1|m.32256 4.638831e-02 -0.9888892 [Genbank]glutaredoxin/malate transporter fusion protein [Chlamydomonas reinhardtii] 
33 c10006_g3_i4|m.32310 7.826191e-07 -1.3364432                                             [Tigrfam]ChlG: chlorophyll synthase ChlG
47 c10010_g1_i4|m.32346 8.609296e-15  1.9188013                          [Genbank]conserved unknown protein [Ectocarpus siliculosus]
48 c10010_g1_i4|m.32348 5.625766e-09  1.8240089                   [Genbank]hypothetical protein THAOC_07134 [Thalassiosira oceanica]
81 c10018_g2_i1|m.32429 2.008500e-04 -0.9899947                                                                                     
89 c10020_g1_i2|m.32459 4.930879e-04 -1.1283138                                                     [Pfam]Zinc-binding dehydrogenase
```

I'd like to compare the genes (all strings in the column "gene") present in each dataframe to see which ones is present in multiple dataframes, so that after the comparison, I'd get a new dataframe telling me which gene is present in which dataframe, e.g.:

```
gene                 DvE.+  DvE.-   DvS.+   DvS.-   EvS.+   EvS.-
c10001_g1_i1|m.32256    0   1   1   0   0   0
c10010_g1_i4|m.32348    1   0   0   0   1   0
```

where the 0 and 1s indicate present or absence.

The output doesn't necessarily have to look like this or use 0 and 1s, but something that will be easy to tell which gene is present in which dataframe.

Comment: Are you sure you are providing all of us non-molecular biologists sufficient information to solve this problem?

Comment: I think so. I presented my input as is, but the "genes" can be treated as just strings. And so my basic question is: how to compare strings (present in one column) in multiple dataframes and present the summary in a new dataframe? This could be applied to anyone else wanting to compare information in multiple dataframes, and not just to molecular biology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I'd do is to rename the dfs to "legit" R names, such as:

- DvE.plus
- DvE.minus

and so on.

Then I'd get the list of all genes (I'll use only 2 hypothetical dataframes for this demonstration);

```
all.genes <- unique(c(DvE.plus$gene, DvE.minus$gene))
```

Then I'd regroup the dataframes in a list for convenience

```
my.dfs <- list(DvE.plus = DvE.plus, DvE.minus = DvE.minus)
```

Then initialise the resulting dataframe

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
result.df <- data.frame(gene=character(0), DvE.plus = numeric(0), 
                        DvE.minus = numeric(0))
```

And using the following loop I'd get what I'm after:

```
for(gene.num in seq_along(all.genes)) {
  result.df[gene.num, "gene"] <- all.genes[gene.num]
  for(df.name in names(my.dfs)) {
    result.df[gene.num,df.name] <- all.genes[gene.num] %in% my.dfs[[df.name]]$gene
  }
}
```

The resulting dataframe will look like this:

```
result.df
                  gene DvE.plus DvE.minus
1 c10001_g1_i1|m.32256        1         0
2 c10006_g3_i4|m.32310        1         0
3 c10010_g1_i4|m.32346        1         0
4 c10010_g1_i4|m.32348        0         1
5 c10018_g2_i1|m.32429        0         1
6 c10020_g1_i2|m.32459        0         1
```